# Webpack app.js not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, webpack

Using Webpack I am getting output file called app.js. The file app.js working great on computer and mobile. But on mobile phones that have android version below 5 app.js not working at all. Even Bootstrap js file that is in app.js not working.
There some es6 code so I convert them to es5 to work on all devices. I wonder what is the problem is?

Here is my webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');


module.exports = {
   mode: 'production',
   entry: {
      app: [
         './resources/js/index.js'
      ]
   },

   output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/assets/js'),
      filename: 'app.js'
   },

   module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
               loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=es2015"
            }
         },
         {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
               fallback: 'style-loader',
               use: [
                  {
                     loader: 'css-loader'
                  }, 
                  {
                     loader: 'postcss-loader',  
                     options: {
                        plugins: [
                           autoprefixer({
                              browsers:['ie >= 8', 'last 4 version']
                           })
                        ],
                        sourceMap: true
                     }
                  },
                  {
                     loader: 'sass-loader'
                  }
               ]
            })
         }
      ]
   },


   plugins: [
      new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: '../css/main.css' }),
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ 
         $: 'jquery',
         jQuery: 'jquery',
         'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
         Popper: 'popper.js',
         WOW: 'wow.js'
      })
   ],

};
```

Comment: You need to include some diagnostics.

Comment: Actually I am new to webpack. So I don't have any diagnostics on my mind. Can you give me an example?

Comment: I meant when you load `app.js` in the browser there should be an error logged to the console.

Comment: There no any errors in console

Comment: Here is the website [link]{https://psdtohtml.uz}

Answer (score 0):

The webpack is actually a build tool. What is does is, the code you have written in ES6 is transpiled to ES5 which is the way most of the browsers understands. One thing you have to check is like check whether you have put any javascript code that is not compatible to older browsers. Because as you are able to see you changes on desktop means your bundling is proper but have some compatibility issues.

Comment: But I included Bootstrap js file that works on mobile devices that have android version below 5. So bootstrap menu toggler must work. But even bootsrap js file not working

Comment: Refer this url & check whether you followed the right way for including bootstrap https://stevenwestmoreland.com/2018/01/how-to-include-bootstrap-in-your-project-with-webpack.html